# How to format Date in JPA query

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

I have a SpringBoot application where I use Repository class to query my Oracle DB table.

Here is how the query and associated function are defined :

```
@Query( value =" SELECT status "+
                   " FROM tb1 " +
                   " WHERE " +
                   " to_date(cob_Date,'dd-MON-yy') = to_date(:cobDate,'yyyy-mm-dd') " +
                   " AND business_Day ='BD3' " +
                   " AND intra_day ='INTRA_06' " +
                   " AND datasource_name =:datasource" +
                   " AND upper(status) = 'COMPLETED' " +
                   " AND frequency = 'MONTHLY' " +
                   " AND processed = 'Y' " +
                   " ORDER BY create_date desc FETCH FIRST 1 rows only"
                   , nativeQuery=true)
    List<String> getImpalaJobStatus(@Param("intraDay") String intraDay,
                                                     @Param("businessDay")  String businessDay,
                                                     @Param("cobDate") LocalDate cobDate,
                                                     @Param("datasource") String datasource);
```

If I run this query in SQL developer then I am getting my results back, however if I run it from my SpringBoot Application it returns nothing.

I suspect I am doing something wrong with the Date field "COB_DATE" and this clause under WHERE:

```
" to_date(cob_Date,'dd-MON-yy') = to_date(:cobDate,'yyyy-mm-dd') " +
```

I tried it as :

```
" cob_Date =:cobDate "
```

but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `cobDate` is being declared as a `LocalDate` in the method signature implies that you *already* have that value in date format.  If so, then the call to `to_date()` in the query is not needed.  Try binding the `LocalDate` value directly:

```java
@Query( value =" SELECT status "+
               " FROM tb1 " +
               " WHERE " +
               " to_date(cob_Date,'dd-MON-yy') = :cobDate " +
               " AND business_Day ='BD3' " +
               " AND intra_day ='INTRA_06' " +
               " AND datasource_name =:datasource" +
               " AND upper(status) = 'COMPLETED' " +
               " AND frequency = 'MONTHLY' " +
               " AND processed = 'Y' " +
               " ORDER BY create_date desc FETCH FIRST 1 rows only"
               , nativeQuery=true)
List<String> getImpalaJobStatus(@Param("intraDay") String intraDay,
                                @Param("businessDay") String businessDay,
                                @Param("cobDate") LocalDate cobDate,
                                @Param("datasource") String datasource);
```

Note that your Oracle JBDC driver should know how to marshall the `LocalDate` value to the database such that the query works.

Comment: @Tin Tim Biegeleisen, Thank you, it worked!